# IIS refuse connection 127.0.0.1

Tags: web-services, iis

I have a problem: I builded a web service in ASP, when I run in Visual studio, work perfectly. I published the web service, I can open asmx page, I can see services description.

I publish a web application for testing the web service in the network and when I run the application for consuming the web service I get the error like IIS refuse connection 127.0.0.1:2332, I have same error if I run te app from local server.

I don't know whats wrong. Firewall is turned off. Another applications works fine in that server.
I hope anyone can help me.

Best regards

Comment: How your web service is setup under IIS? As a sub application under default website or default website itself is pointing to web service folder?

Comment: Hi Mohsin-mehmood thanks. It,s a sub application under server default. In server default there are another applications. They are working fine and this web service point to folder.

Comment: Learn site bindings first https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: @angel_neo if your webservice is setup as a sub-application under default website then its url should be `http://localhost/{Sub-Application-Alias}:port` instead of `http://localhost:port`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved, my mistake. When I build the web service and the app for consuming the ws, VStudio uses IIS express, and create that port for the web service (2332). So in production server, I changed in webconfig file the reference to the web service under `<client>` tag:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/DWAbrirDocumento/DescargarDocumentacion.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DWBajarDocumentoSoap" contract="ServiceRef_BajarDocumentacion.DWBajarDocumentoSoap" name="DWBajarDocumentoSoap" />
</client>
```

Then, the app point to the web server.

thanks Mohsin, thanks Lex Li.

PD, anyone knows how can I close this Answer?